# Rails 4: sort by association attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Person has_many :dogs

Dog belongs_to :person

Dog has_many :bones

Bone belongs_to :dog

I want to find the bone associated with each dog a given person owns and sort the results by bone_buried_date

Something like...

```
bones = []
some_person.dogs.each do |dog|
    bones << dog.bones.first
end
bones.sort_by{ |e| e[:bone_buried_date] }
```

Seems clumsy. Wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Why are you saying your example doesn't work?  the `order` is on the `bones` association, so it would expect a `bone` attribute, which is what you're providing.

Comment: Edited to add person.

Comment: Edited all around to better reflect actual scenario

Comment: You could add a HMT relation... `person has many bones through dogs`... that would let you do` some_person.bones.order(:bone_buried_date)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
Bone.where(dog: Dog.where(person: some_person)).order(:bone_buried_date)
```